Is there any way to trim multiple PNG images in Photoshop?
I am creating some player image cutouts for my projects. I want the image in a PNG format, and it should be cropped on all sides.
Now, when I have multiple PNGs in a single project, I am cropping and exporting as PNG separately for each and every photo.
Is there any way that I can crop all of the images together at one time?
The screenshot below shows my current setup.


if they are all layers.. just crop the image.


set up a "trim/crop" action for a folder containing only your images to be trimmed

set up a layered PSD with your images on separate layers.  Modify canvas size.   Set each layer as a layer comp.   Export layer comps as files.


